# Powershell script to create folder for groups with extensionAttribute1 set

Tags: powershell

Hi I want to write a powershell scrip that creates a folder for groups in a specific OU where I have set the extensionAttribute1.

> Get-ADGroup -filter * -SearchBase "OU=Groups,OU=Test,DC=test,DC=Domain,DC=en" -properties * | where {$_.extensionAttribute1}| select-object samaccountname, extensionAttribute1

so I get the list of groups with extensionAttribute1 and with

> Get-ChildItem D:\Test

I get the list of already created folders.
What is the best way to compare these two lists and create one for the groups for which no folder is created yet?

Comment: So, to rephrase, you're looking to compare the group names from `Get-ADGroup`, to the folder names returned by `Get-ChildItem D:\Test`? Then, create the folders based on which one's missing?

Comment: the idea is that for a group (e.g. Test) if the extensionAttribute1 is set to folder, a new folder with the group names is created on the server drive D:\ if no folder exists yet

Comment: That's still confusing, probably why noone has answered yet lol. You want a single folder for the group names, or separate folders per group that has the value of Folder in extensionAttribute1?

Comment: I would like to create a new directory for each group where the atriubet is set that has the group name.
and of course the script should not try to create a folder if it already exists

Comment: Can we see your attempt at this?

Comment: i have a start:

$Project = Get-ADGroup -filter * -SearchBase "OU=Groups,DC=Domain,DC=com" -properties * | where {$_.extensionAttribute1}| select-object samaccountname, extensionAttribute1

foreach ($p in $project){
    $Foldername = $p.samaccountname 
    $Folder_link = $SMB_Link + '/0_projects/' + $Foldername
        if (Test-Path -Path $Folder_link) {
      #exit script
        }
            else {
                      create the project folder if not present 
                     }

Comment: Can you update your post with it and not post it in the comments. As you can see, it's hard to read. When I get off work, I can help.

Answer (score 0):

Given you're scenario, you don't have to use `Get-ChildItem` if you just want to see if the folder already exists. Then, you would only need `Test-Path` and use a loop to test for each folder.

```
Get-ADGroup -filter * -SearchBase "OU=Groups,OU=Test,DC=test,DC=Domain,DC=en" -properties "extensionAttribute1" | 
    Where-Object -FilterScript { $_.extensionAttribute1 -eq "Folder" } | 
    ForEach-Object `
        -Begin { $path = "D:\Test\"  } `
        -Process {
            if (-not (Test-Path -LiteralPath ($path + $_.Name))) {
                New-Item -Path $path -Name $_.Name -ItemType "Directory" | Out-Null 
            }
        }
```